# how to format a date in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

**EDIT:**

How to format a date in Microsoft SQL Server with format `dd-mm-yyyy` to format `yyyy-mm-dd`. This format is not given in SQL Server but a similar format is available `yyyy/mm/dd`

Is there any such function in SQL Server 2008 or 2005?

Comment: Why can't you use the T-SQL convert function?

Comment: I was about to ask why you need to format in SQL server but then I re-read the message - are the dates being *stored* as strings rather than as DateTime types?

Comment: What other format do you want to use??? And why not using CONVERT?? That's **THE** defined way to do it - why fight it??

Comment: Are you looking for help on using string manipulation functins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), GetDate(), 126)
```

By using CHAR(10), this will chop off the time portion, which you dont need.

ps. Replace GetDate() with the date you need converting

EDIT: [Cast and Convert](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) does show this conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a real "datetime" column, then the date is not stored in any particular string format but in a (fixed) binary format.

Only when displaying the results in Query Analyzer (or Management Studio) the internal format is converted into a string. If you query that column, you will get back a real date (not a string).

Answer (score 0):

You said that you have stored the value in a string format, so first you need to convert it back to date using **convert(date,columnname,103)** then you can format it as you required.

**Example** select  format(convert(date,'29-03-2019',103),'yyyy-MM-dd')

it converts date string to dd-mm-yyyy then formats to yyyy-mm-dd string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SYSDATETIME(), 104) AS [DD.MM.YYYY]
```